# react-native-elements Button is not a perfect rectangle

Tags: react-native, button, react-native-elements

I have a `button` in my app that needs to be a perfect rectangle, but with no styling attached to it, there's a tiny default border-radius to it. How can I resolve this?

```
<Button
      title="Next"
      onPress={() => // Next stuff}
      buttonStyle={{
          backgroundColor: "#000000",
          width: 'auto',
      }}
      />
```

Comment: Share the code for the `<Button/>` component.

Comment: `borderWidth:0` is how you would change the width of the border